# share point excel service

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have developed share point site for document library. users can upload/ download documents from the share point site.

But when we try to open an excel file from the share point website it prompt below error. Can any one have an idea about it.

Error:

Excel service
The trial period for SharePoint Server has expired.

Comment: Have you considered that *the trial period for SharePoint Server has expired.*..?

Answer (score 0):

A look around Technet suggests that this is a false alarm in 2010, so it might be worthwile checking the Health Analyser rules in 2013, too:

> This is a false alarm. It is not time bombed and your farm will continue to work. If you click on the health analyzer warning you will see “
>   "Explanation : The licensing information not available". The MSSx sku does not have licencing module since its a free product. By default the rule "Trial period for this product is about to expire." is enabled in the health analyzer. The bug here is that we didn't disable this rule. The rule kicks in and its unable to find the licensing module and throws an exception (you can find it in the LOGS folder).
>
> Workaround: In central admin go to "Central Admin" => Monitoring => "Review Rule Definitions" => click on "Trial period for this product is about to expire" rule under configuration and edit it. Uncheck the "Enabled" checkbox.

[source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/644ab342-4eaa-468c-95c1-f345a4f65f26/the-trial-period-for-this-product-has-expired-sharepoint-foundation-2010?forum=sharepointadminprevious)

and another article on the [msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joerg_sinemus/archive/2010/07/14/microsoft-sharepoint-foundation-2010-and-microsoft-search-server-express-2010-trial-period-has-expired.aspx)